# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop for React Native in my Code in Asynchronous stateless component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Facing Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop** for React Native in my Code in Asynchronous stateless component.

I am trying to call an asynchronous method using a stateless component. I am trying to call an API inside the async storage.

So Basically I need to get the email from Asyncstorage and need to pass that link into the API. I am trying to do that but getting Error Facing Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

````
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import PatientScreen from './Patient';
import OtpScreen from './Otp';
import Settings from './settings';
import SearchDoctor from './SearchDoctor';


const PatientPage = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(true);
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const [text, setText] = React.useState({
        email: ''
    });
    const [routes] = React.useState([
        { key: 'music', title: 'Music', icon: 'queue-music' },
        { key: 'search', title: 'Search', icon: 'magnify' },
        { key: 'settings', title: 'Settings', icon: 'cog-outline' },
    ]);

    const getData = async () => {
        if (!expanded)
            try {
                AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key').then((data) => {
                    let value = JSON.stringify(data);
                    setText({
                        ...text,
                        email: value.email
                    })
                    fetch("http://localhost:8090/patient/fetchData", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        },
                        "body": JSON.stringify({
                            email: text.toShowLoginEmail
                        })
                    }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                })
            } catch (e) {
                // error reading value
            }
    }

    const handleValidUser = () => {
        setExpanded(true);
        getData();
    }

    handleValidUser();

    const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
        music: HomeScreen,
        search: SearchDoctor,
        settings: Settings,
    });

    return (
        <BottomNavigation
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            renderScene={renderScene}
        />
    );
}

export default PatientPage;```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that You call `handleValidUser();` in the body of the component, and the trance goes like this `handleValidUser() -> getData() -> setText()` .

So `handleValidUser` is called on every render, but the function itself modifies the state, which causes a re-render and another call of `handleValidUser`, thus creating a loop

consider using `useEffect` to call the function only once, or only when certain dependencies change

```
// Don't forget to import { useEffect } from 'react'
useEffect(() => {
 handleValidUser();
}, []);
```

In this case, the dependency array is empty, thus the function will be called only once, when the component mounts (much like `componentDidMount`. For more complicated use of the dependency array please see [React useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Apparently, there are some dependencies so the following might do the trick.

```
const getData = React.useCallback(async () => {
          if (!expanded){
            try { .... 
          }
        }, [expanded]); //add expanded as a dependency
```

```
const handleValidUser = React.useCallback(() => {
        setExpanded(true);
        getData();
    }, [setExpanded, getData)
```

Finally, modify the useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => { 
  handleValidUser() 
}, [handleValidUser]);
```

So this way, every time a dependency of `useCallback` is changed, the function is being changed too, which causes the useEffect to fire again.

Comment: Tried this error is gone but API is not yet called on load

Comment: That is because `if(!expanded)` won't work. I will modify the code please, try that.

Comment: Yes Please do modify and give me thanks. I am quite new to react native